# bundle failure with error: java.lang.Exception: ORPHANED

Tags: jpa, bundle, apache-karaf, apache-felix

While bringing up one of the application we are making some calls to DB, but i could see that those calls are failing with below exception,

```
org.osgi.service.coordinator.CoordinationException: Coordination failed
    at org.apache.felix.coordinator.impl.CoordinationImpl.end(CoordinationImpl.java:255)
    at org.apache.felix.coordinator.impl.CoordinationHolder.end(CoordinationHolder.java:56)
    at org.apache.aries.jpa.blueprint.impl.JpaInterceptor.postCallWithReturn(JpaInterceptor.java:93)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.proxy.Collaborator.postInvoke(Collaborator.java:98)
    at Proxya2d2cd71_d4e4_434e_a965_b48799d154f7.findById(Unknown Source)
    at 
    ..............
    Caused by: java.lang.Exception: ORPHANED
    at org.osgi.service.coordinator.Coordination.<clinit>(Coordination.java:88)
    at org.apache.felix.coordinator.impl.CoordinationHolder.finalize(CoordinationHolder.java:178)
    at java.lang.System$2.invokeFinalize(System.java:1270)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer.runFinalizer(Finalizer.java:98)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer.access$100(Finalizer.java:34)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:210)
```

Any information about this "java.lang.Exception: ORPHANED"

Comment: Hi Subhashc, I think we need a piece of code to be able to help with this, not only the stacktrace. This error was also reported to Apache Felix a while ago and they closed as Won't Fix as it was an invalid scenario at the time. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @Brother for the reply, apologies for not sharing the code, i was mainly interested in the error. The possible scenario in which this error can be seen.